# have been trying to create an mpeg dash player using but video is not responding

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

please check this code out and help me see what am doing wrong the file wont play in video. the segments are first appended to an array and then appended to the source buffer when the sourcebuffer updateend is called

```
$(function() {

    var video = function () {
        this.segmentArray = [];
        this.version = "PressPause 1.0.0",
        this.videoPlayer = document.querySelectorAll("video")[0];
        this.source = new MediaSource();
        this.segmentCheck = 0;
        this.lastTime = 0;
        this.duration = 0;
        this.bandwidth = 0;
        this.duration = "";
        this.InitializationSegment = null;
        this.mpdfile = null;
        this.baseurl = "";
        this.playingSegmentIndex = 0;
        this.bufferUpdated = false;
        this.initRange = 0;
        this.width = 200;
        this.height = 200;
        this.segments = 0;
        this.period = 0;
        this.duration = 0;
        this.codecs = String.EMPTY;
        this.representation = null;
        this.videoPlayer.src = this.mediaUrl;
        this.videoPlayer.pause();
        this.videoPlayer.width = this.width;
        this.videoPlayer.height = this.height;
        var self = this;
        this.videoPlayer.addEventListener("play", function() {
            console.log("from videoplayer play event");
        });
        self.videoPlayer.addEventListener("canplay", function () {
            console.log("can play");
            self.videoPlayer.play();
        });
        self.videoPlayer.addEventListener("loadstart", function () {
            console.log("started loading metadate");
        });
        self.videoPlayer.addEventListener("onloadedmetadata", function() {
            console.log("loaded metadata");
        });
        self.videoPlayer.addEventListener("oncanplaythrough", function() {
            console.log("can play through");
        });



        self.videoPlayer.addEventListener("sourceended", function() {
            console.log("has ended");
        });
        self.videoPlayer.addEventListener("onaddtrack", function() {
            console.log("added track");
        });
        self.videoPlayer.addEventListener("play", function() {
            console.log("called play");
        });
        self.videoPlayer.addEventListener("update", function() {
            console.log("updated");
        });
        self.videoPlayer.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
            console.log("has loaded data");
        });

        //this.sourceBuffer= null;o
        this.startInit = false;
        this.source.addEventListener("sourceopen", function() {
            console.log("source has opened " + self.source.readyState);
        });
        this.source.addEventListener("sourceopen", this.init.call(self), false);
        this.source.addEventListener("sourceclose", function() {
            console.log("mediasource closed " +self.source.readyState);
        }, false);
        this.source.addEventListener("sourceended", function () {
            console.log("mediasource ended "+self.source.readyState);
        }, false);
        this.source.addEventListener("endOfStream", function() {
            console.log("have come to end of stream");
        });
        this.sourceBuffer = null;

    }
    video.prototype.timeToDownLoad = function (range) {
        var videoself = this;
        var vidDur = range.split("-");
        // Time = size * 8 / bitrate
        return (((vidDur[1] - vidDur[0]) * 8) / videoself.bandwidth);
    }

    video.prototype.fetchMpd = function (filename) {
        if (this.startInit == false) {
            this.startInit = true;
            var videoself = this;
            var httprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httprequest.open("GET", "PressPause/Media/" + filename + "mpd");
            httprequest.send();
            httprequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                var self = this;
                if (self.readyState == 4) {
                    if (self.status == 200) {
                        videoself.mpdfile = new DOMParser().parseFromString(self.responseText, "application/xml");
                        videoself.processMpd.call(videoself,videoself.mpdfile);


                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
    video.prototype.processDuration = function(durationTemp) {

        var worker = durationTemp.split("PT")[1];
        var hour = worker.split("H")[0].slice(0, 1);
        var mins = worker.split("H")[1].slice(0, 2);
        var secss = worker.split("M")[1].slice(0, 5); 

        console.log("the hour is " + hour +" mins "+mins+ " secs "+secss);
    };

    video.prototype.processMpd=function(mpd) {
        this.InitializationSegment = mpd.querySelectorAll("Initialization")[0];
        this.initRange = this.InitializationSegment.getAttribute("range");
        this.period = mpd.querySelectorAll("Period")[0];
        var tempduration = this.period.getAttribute("duration");
        this.processDuration(tempduration);

        this.representation = mpd.querySelectorAll("Representation")[0];
        this.bandwidth = this.representation.getAttribute("bandwidth");
        this.videoPlayer.width = this.representation.getAttribute("width");
        this.videoPlayer.height = this.representation.getAttribute("height");
        this.codecs = this.representation.getAttribute("codecs");
        this.segments = mpd.querySelectorAll("SegmentURL");
        this.processRange(this.initRange);
        this.startInitialization("the url", this.initRange);
        console.log(this.initRange);
    }

    video.prototype.startInitialization = function (url, range) {
        var videoSelf = this;
        while (videoSelf.source.readyState!="open") {
            console.log("mediaSource not open");
        }
        var codecs = 'video/mp4;codecs="avc1.64001E"';
        console.log("can play codec " + codecs + videoSelf.videoPlayer.canPlayType(codecs));
        //'video/mp4;codecs="' + videoSelf.codecs + '"'
        videoSelf.sourceBuffer = videoSelf.source.addSourceBuffer(codecs);
        videoSelf.sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", function () {

            console.log("updateend occurs when the append or remove operation has ended");
            console.log("append mode " + videoSelf.sourceBuffer.AppendMode);
            console.log("buffered below");
            console.log(videoSelf.sourceBuffer.buffered);
            console.log(videoSelf.sourceBuffer.updating); 
        });
        videoSelf.sourceBuffer.addEventListener("update", function () {
            console.log("update occurs when the append or remove operation has ended successfully");
            console.log("append mode " +videoSelf.sourceBuffer.AppendMode);
            console.log("buffered below");
            console.log(videoSelf.sourceBuffer.buffered);
            console.log(videoSelf.sourceBuffer.updating);

        });
        videoSelf.sourceBuffer.addEventListener("error", function () {
            console.log("error occurs when the append or remove operation is aborted by calling abort");
            console.log("append mode " + videoSelf.sourceBuffer.AppendMode);
            console.log("buffered below");
            console.log(videoSelf.sourceBuffer.buffered);
            console.log(videoSelf.sourceBuffer.updating);
        });

        if (url && range) {
            console.log("start processing");
            var httprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httprequest.open("GET", "PressPause/Media/videomp4", true);
            httprequest.responseType = "arrayBuffer";
            httprequest.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=" + range);
            httprequest.send();
            httprequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4) {
                    if (this.status == 200) {
                        try {

                            videoSelf.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(httprequest.response));
                            videoSelf.videoPlayer.readyState = 2;
                            videoSelf.videoPlayer.pause();
                            videoSelf.videoPlayer.play();

                            console.log("source is "+videoSelf.source.readyState);
                            console.log("player is " + videoSelf.videoPlayer.readyState);
                            console.log("player error is " + videoSelf.videoPlayer.error);

                            videoSelf.sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", videoSelf.startProcessingSegments.bind(videoSelf));


                        } catch (e) {

                            console.log(e.message + "from startInitialization " + e);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });


        } else {
            throw new Error("range and url cannot be undefined");
        }
    }

    video.prototype.startProcessingSegments = function () {

        var self = this;
        console.log(self);
        console.log("starting to fetch data");
        self.sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", self.isupdating.bind(self), false);
        self.isupdating.call(self);
        console.log("from startProcessingSegments " + self.source.activeSourceBuffers);
        console.log("from startProcessingSegments " + self.playingSegmentIndex);

        console.log("can play type= " + self.videoPlayer.canPlayType('video/mp4;codecs="' + self.codecs + '"'));

        self.bufferUpdated = true;
        console.log(self.source.sourceBuffers);
        console.log(self.sourceBuffer.buffered);
    }

    video.prototype.isupdating = function () {

        var self = this;

        self.videoPlayer.removeEventListener("updateend", self.startProcessingSegments);
        for (self.playingSegmentIndex; self.playingSegmentIndex < self.segments.length; self.playingSegmentIndex++) {
            console.log(self.sourceBuffer.updating);
            self.checkSegmentArray.call(self);
            self.playSegment("url", self.segments[self.playingSegmentIndex].getAttribute("mediaRange"));
        }


    };
    video.prototype.addingSegmentIndex = 0;
    video.prototype.checkSegmentArray = function () {

        var videoS = this;
        if (videoS.segmentArray.length > 0 && !videoS.sourceBuffer.updating) {
            var thevideo = videoS.segmentArray.shift();
            videoS.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(thevideo);
            console.log("adding segment called"+videoS.addingSegmentIndex +" times");
            console.log(thevideo);
            videoS.addingSegmentIndex++;
        }
        console.log(videoS.videoPlayer.readyState);
        console.log(videoS.sourceBuffer);
        console.log(videoS.segmentArray.length + " items left");
        console.log(videoS.sourceBuffer.updating);
        console.log(videoS.source.readyState);
        console.log("from checkSegmentArray");
        console.log("\n");
    }


    video.prototype.playSegment = function (url, range) {
        console.log("it happend again");

        var videoSelf = this;

        var httprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httprequest.open("GET", "PressPause/Media/videomp4", true);
        httprequest.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=" + range);
        httprequest.responseType = "arrayBuffer";
        httprequest.send();
        httprequest.onreadystatechange=function(e) {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    videoSelf.segmentArray.push(new Uint8Array(httprequest.response));
                    videoSelf.checkSegmentArray.call(videoSelf);

                }
            }
        }
    };

    video.prototype.processRange= function(range) {
        var rangeArray = range.toString().split("-");
        var first = rangeArray[0];
        var second = rangeArray[1];
        console.log("first: " + first, "second " + second);
    }

    video.prototype.init = function () {

        console.log("calling mpd");
        if (this.startInit==false) {
            this.fetchMpd("video");

        }
    }


the new mpd generated using ffmpeg how can i process it in javascript what should i be looking for
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT110.2S" minBufferTime="PT1S" profiles="urn:webm:dash:profile:webm-on-demand:2012">
<Period id="0" start="PT0S" duration="PT110.2S">
<AdaptationSet id="0" mimeType="video/webm" codecs="vp8" lang="eng" width="1280" height="720" bitstreamSwitching="true" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
<Representation id="0" bandwidth="134033">
<BaseURL>C:\Users\solo\newfilemuxer.webm</BaseURL>
<SegmentBase indexRange="1223146-1223345">
<Initialization range="0-249"/>
</SegmentBase>
</Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
</Period>
```

Comment: video element readystate is always 0 even when i have appended to the buffer at least once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take the codec attribute information of the MPD, maybe that's an issue. Does your content play when you append the segments directly to the source buffer? Can you also post your MPD with access to the content? Does the content play using the [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki) or [bitdash](http://www.dash-player.com) MPEG-DASH players?

Comment: i have posted the mpd file produced it using mp4box thanks when i append directly to source buffer i get an error that source buffer is still updating with either appendbuffer,remove. i also noticed that after about 56 segments are added then the source buffer stays in the updating state for a long time

Comment: in the posted MPD, there is a text in one of the mediaRange attributes, but that's not your problem I guess. Can you concat the init segment with one of the media segments and play it with a media player such as VLC or similar. 
did you test the content with an other dash player? MP4Client can also be used. Can you post the URL to the content?
can you split audio and video tracks, and give it a try?

Comment: Chrome plays webm as well as mp4 ... you can see a lot of examples here http://www.dash-player.com/demo

Comment: I produced an mpd file using ffmpeg before i was using mp4box the some of the elements seem to be different so while before i was looking for segments now i have adaptationset and segmentbase how can i process this in terms of after the initialization segment what should i be appending to the sourcebuffer

Comment: you have to use the -frag parameter to have seperated segments instead of one big file, e.g.: MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 4000 -rap -segment-name segment_ output_2400k.mp4
here you can find a step-by-step tutorial for that here: http://www.dash-player.com/blog/2014/11/mpeg-dash-content-generation-using-mp4box-and-x264/

Comment: if you have used mp4box or ffmpeg in c# can you please send me how you passed the arguments in using c# process or processinfo